# War on Greenland without destroying earth

Tags: warfare, weapons, near-future

### Background

Let's assume our world, just like it is today, but it has taken a different path about five years ago. We are about five years in future.

Any country has joined one of two powerful "groups". (It's like a second cold war.)

**1) The East**

- Asia
- Europe
- Australia

**2) The West**

- North, Middle, and South America

---

### What happened

Unfortunately, they didn't peacefully finish their world dividing. Still neutral are:

- Africa (which has still its own problems)
- Arctica (which is still melting and has no interesting resources)
- Antarctica (two military groups saying they own it haven't found each other yet. Maybe they just aren't interested in doing this.)
- Greenland. *(Where our war is going to happen)*

---

### More details about the opponents

- They aren't interested in nuking each other. (Note: They want to own everything, not destroy everything. Both think that they're strong enough to win.)
- Any satellites have been destroyed. (And no new ones have been deployed for cost reasons.)
- War should happen with huge army of trained soldiers for the *Eastern* side (so many young people who just became full-aged can join there)
- Nearly no men for the *Western* side: automated killing robots are their weapon. (But the East found out how to destroy them)

---

### My Question: What will the war look like?

This includes:

- What strategies will be used/usefull?
- What weapons will be used/usefull?

Comment: If you assume everyone has gone insane and is acting irrational, you make it really difficult to answer. If everyone is completely out of his mind, how do you determine what weapon he will choose and what strategy he follows?

Comment: Why out of his mind? Some of the specifications seem to be strange, but there are reasons, coming from my plotline mostly – and I'm sure I will find enough reasons why they act strange seen from "war effectiveness point", but that's not the only point of view. Peoples opinions and to be elected again are important as well.

Comment: *"There are resons"* for Japan to be allied with China against the U.S.A., for India to be allied with Pakistan against Canada, for Iran to be allied with Israel against Mexico, for Finland, Hungary, Poland and Romania to be allied with Russia against Brazil? *"There are reasons"* for Europe to use massed infantry instead of top of the line technology? *"There are reasons"* for two mighty military blocks to fight to the death over the control of a 2 kilometers thick ice sheet? This is either a *very* good or a most silly story.

Comment: @AlexP good point. But it's that the oppenents fight with all their power. (That's why not nuking anything.) Think about it more like middle east today: There are ressources, it would be good publicity to wind and look bad to lose; the public (or parts of it) mostly want the war and think it's right; and maybe it could be usefull…)

Comment: Basically terminators in ice with no nukes?

Comment: In Greenland, what they would be fighting for, what's going to be the targets? US Navy alone is strong enough to deny all other nations combined access to Greenland, and pulverize any force that happen to land there.

Comment: "*Arctica (which is still melting and has no interesting ressources)*". The Arctic Sea is thought to be chock full of oil & natural gas.

Comment: Why in the heck would anyone want to fight on Greenland?

Comment: The west loses. The East can deploy non-nuclear electromagnetic pulse generators across Greenland and shut down your robot army.

Comment: Why aren't they fighting to expand their influence in Africa instead of Greenland? There are a lot more resources and people in Africa, it's also a lot bigger. The use of massive infantry armies is really an outdated military tactics. Already in the time of WWI, it became a suicide to amass a large number of troop and launch an assault. You put long time enemies like India/Pakistan, Saudi Arabia/Israel/Iran on the same side despite they hate each other. We can't know how they will fight since it makes no sense for them to be allied.

Comment: Again on the Greenland note - Greenland is actually pretty small, all things considered - most map projections artificially inflate its size. It's actually about the same size as Mexico

Answer (score 1):

5 years is not very far in the future.

Most likely technology is what you see today, but with minor small improvements.

It looks, however, in contrast that in this short time **the world politically has altered significantly and drastically**. The world has been divided on 'land mass' (except Australia) and not any historical affiliations. A major element of your story could simply be the back story of how this occurred - which could be intriguing as a story in its own right.

You did  mention 'cold war' though - it is useful to therefore study this historical conflict closely. A few points about this period that may interest you:

- It started at the end of World War II - when two superpowers emerged with (mostly) equal capabilities after a devastating conflict
- Conflicts were more 'proxy wars' of influencing others rather than direct, as a direct conflict may result in mutual destruction.
- The mutual capabilities of both, meant the Cold War was more concentrated in espionage, foreign influence, and technological improvement.
- 'Taking territory' meant less than having an influence over its government - this was essentially what has kept borders fairly constant since WWII.

Therefore you can't ignore the oceans or space - access in these environments are the primary delivery mechanisms of your sphere of influence.

However as said above - I would be more intrigued by the back story of the major alteration of the geopolitical landscape, rather than the unlikely taking over of Greenland.

Answer (score 0):

For the little trained soldiers, they should use the robot destroying weapons that they have found out.  For the strategy I propose they destroy the robots quickly before the robots get up to much and then destroy any other ones as they arrive.  And they should try to get along with each other and to stay warm.

For the automated killing robots: I propose they stay a distance from Greenland and attack incoming supply ships / planes, staying clear of the little soldiers (who can destroy robots).  The little soldiers will get bored, cold and hungry.  When they get really cold and hungry the killing robots can see if they have gotten killable; if not, wait a while more.